# PHP table alignment is not correct inside foreach Loop

Tags: php, html-table

I want to display Array data in a table with 3 columns in a row using foreach loop with a condition.

**Coding**

```
$value[]='a';
$value[]='b';
$value[]='c';
$value[]='d';
$value[]='e';

echo '<table width=30% border=1>';  
    echo '<tr>';
        $counter=1; 

        foreach($value as $key){
            if($counter>=3){ // if there is more than 3 elements, go to next Row

                    if($counter%3==0){ // when the Array hit 3th,6th,9th,12th.... element
                        echo '</tr><tr><td>';               
                        echo $key;  
                        echo '</td>';                   
                    }else{
                        echo '<td>';
                        echo $key;              
                        echo '</td>';                       
                    }
            }else{
                echo '<td>';                
                echo $key;      
                echo '</td>';                   
            }           
            $counter++;
        }
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

I double check the coding and didn't manage to find the error.... my output is the bottom of the image. However, the correct one should be top of the image. Please take a look at the photo

[image]

Anyone know what's wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change modulas condition with

```
if($counter % 3 == 1)
```

and you will get what you desire

Answer (score 0):

You have "if counter >= 3" so you are hitting that condition on your 3rd element, not AFTER your third element.

Comment: hi! thx for your info. I change it to "counter>3" , the output looks even more weird. All data display in 1 row with 5 columns

Answer (score 0):

Change the initialization of your counter to `$counter=0;`